# BATCH bat1.bat Call external function in bat2.bat

Tags: function, batch-file, call, external

I would like to have two bat files.

- BAT1 : list of functions
- BAT2 : calls one specific function in BAT1.

BAT1 :

```
@echo off              
:ALPHA                
echo ALPHA             
goto end            

:BETA            
echo BETA                        
goto end            

:end            
pause
```

BAT2 :

```
@echo off             
call bat1.bat             
goto BETA
```

This obviously does not work. I tried some other changes without result.

BAT1 : returns ALPHA and never BETA.
What I whant to do is to RUN BAT2, which will call BETA in BAT1.

If you think it is possible, please help me. I have found no solutions on internet else how to call a value in an external file. But it does not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use arguments when calling bat1. Then in bat1 check the input parameter and go to the label you want.

Comment: OK I've found how to, thank you for your quick answer. With an argument it works perfectly. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

@July Mixer: basically it works like this:

BAT1 :

```
@echo off 
goto %1             
:ALPHA                
echo ALPHA             
goto end            

:BETA            
echo BETA                        
goto end            

:end            
pause
```

BAT2 :

```
@echo off             
call bat1.bat BETA           
echo returned
```

`%1`is the first argument (aka parameter) given. (in this case `BETA`)

**EDIT** adding some errorhandling to BAT1:

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="" findstr /i /x /c:":%1" %~df0 >nul 2>&1 &&goto %1
echo wrong parameter
exit /b

:alpha 
echo Alpha
goto :eof

:beta 
echo Beta
goto :eof
```

Comment: I'd prefer `if not "$1" == "" goto %1`

Comment: `if not "%1" == "" goto %1` to be correct. Yes, of course. Therefore I wrote "basically".

Comment: Yeah, just adding something. You had my +1.